# how to pass a variable to an object method

Tags: javascript, variables

I have an object in Javascript which resembles the below

```
var configs = {
    init: function() {
        this.var1 = 'variable 1',
        this.var2 = 'variable 2'
    },

    outer: {
        inner: {
            inner_var1: 'inner variable 1',
            inner_var2: 'inner variable 2',
            inner_var3: 'inner variable 3',
            inner_function: function(item_1, item2) {
                console.log(this.var1);
            }
        }
    }
}

var config = Object.create(configs);
config.init();
document.config = config;
```

I need to inject a variable set in the init method, into the outer.inner.inner_function method. But the caveat is, I cannot pass any more variables into the inner_function method parameter list. (The 'inner' object is a set of options for a third party plugin, and the function is defined by the plugin and only takes two parameters)

How can I reference this.var1 from within an inner method?

Thanks

Comment: You can use `arguments` to get access to all arguments passed to a function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

Comment: It all depends how you call the function `inner_function`. Could you provide the problematic call?

Comment: @DoMiNeLa. arguments will only get the value of item_1 and item_2 parameters. i am asking how to pass further parameters to the function without adding item_3 for example

Comment: If you pass more arguments to the function, they will be available in `arguments`.

Comment: @trincot.  I am using a plugin and 'inner' is just an object of settings for the plugin to use. They are defined by the plugin author. So in my case, i would use this object something like `plugin.init(document.config.outer.inner)`

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10. As i mentioned in the original question, this method is part of a third party plugin, and that method only takes two parameters.  The plugin calls the method, not me. I am only defining what the method does.  I therefore cannot just add another parameter to the method call

Comment: So replace that with `plugin.init(document.config.outer.inner.bind(config))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objects don't have any automatic reference to their containing objects, so within the `inner` object there's no built-in way to get to `outer` or `config`. You need to pass the object explicitly.

So you need to define it as:

```
inner_function: function(config, item_1, item_2) {
    console.log(config.var1);
}
```

and call it as:

```
document.config.outer.inner.inner_function(document.config, i1, i2);
```

If you want to be able to access the containers without passing them as arguments, you need to put them explicitly into the object.

```
var configs = {
    init: function() {
        this.var1 = 'variable 1',
        this.var2 = 'variable 2'
    },

    outer: {
        inner: {
            inner_var1: 'inner variable 1',
            inner_var2: 'inner variable 2',
            inner_var3: 'inner variable 3',
            inner_function: function(item_1, item2) {
                console.log(this.parent.parent.var1);
            }
        }
    }
}
configs.outer.inner.parent = configs.outer;
configs.outer.parent = configs;
```

Comment: As the third party plugin is what calls this method, I cannot add any further parameters. however, the parent.parent.var1 seems like a good option.  thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Your problem happens because you do not have the `inner_function` called with the right value for `this`. So make sure `this` is correctly bound to it. For example:

```
plugin.init(document.config.outer.inner.bind(document.config))
```